# Programatically tell the difference between data

Tags: c#, file, data-conversion

Im converting mass files to XML and each file is either XML, JSON, CSV or PSV. To do the conversion I need to know what data type the file is without looking at the file extension (Some are coming from API's). Someone suggested that I try parse each file by each of the types until you get a success but that is pretty inefficient and CSV cant be easily parsed as it is essentially just a text file (Same as PSV).

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do? Thanks.

Comment: You could use regex to attempt to recognise different syntax styles

Comment: This is why god invented file extensions 

Comment: @ScottPerham When data comes from a stream there is no extension

Comment: if content from Api Then its should returns content type like ````Application/json````

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj Not neccessarily, what about `application/xml` or even `application/html` or ...?

Comment: If there is any potential confusion as to which file format is included in the data stream then "the protocol" will usually tell you... if this is bespoke then that should be implemented... for example, in HTTP it's "content type"

Comment: if file is uploaded to the api it autmaticalley addded to a content types to the header so only i guess it

Comment: Like when upload a Json file its automatically added header content type  like  ````application/json```` and same as csv file its automatically added content type  ````application/txt````

Comment: so it will be received a response from server i guess @kieran Devlin check your content type from api response..

Comment: In most cases the first row of the file indicates the type.

Comment: When it comes to APIs remember: "The more complicated they are, the more they have to help you out" David Lightman, 1983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have some kind of "pre-parsing":

- Either it starts with an XML declaration, or directly with the root node, first character of an [XML file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) should be `<`.
- First character of a [JSON file](http://json.org/) can only be `{` if the JSON is built on an object, or `[` if the JSON is built on an array.
- For CSV and PSV (I guess PSV stands for Point-Separated Values?), each line of the file represent a specific record.

So by checking first character, you may find XML and/or JSON parsing is pointless.

Parsing the first line of the file should be enough to decide if the file format is CSV or PSV.

Comment: You can't use any of these because PSV (Pipe separated values) and CSV can not have a header and the first character can be either "{", "[" or "<".

Comment: If the CSV and PSV files may start with `{`, `[`, or `<`, first try CSV and PSV parsing (at least on the first line), and, if they fail, try the other parsings (starting with the first character)